Why can't I get the parent process' task_struct pointer in libbpf program?
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
typedef int pid_t;

#include "execsnoop.h"

// Define a hash map to store events
struct {
  __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
  __uint(max_entries, 10240);  // Maximum number of entries in the hash map
  __type(key, pid_t);          // Key type: PID
  __type(value, struct event); // Value type: event
} execs SEC(".maps");

// Define a perf event map
struct {
  __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY);
  __uint(key_size, sizeof(u32));
  __uint(value_size, sizeof(u32));
} events SEC(".maps");

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_execve")
int tracepoint__syscalls__sys_enter_execve(
    struct trace_event_raw_sys_enter *ctx) {
  static const struct event empty_event = {};

  // Get current process ID and timestamp
  u64 id = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
  pid_t pid = (pid_t)id;
  u64 ts = bpf_ktime_get_ns();

  // Get the parent PID of the current process
  struct task_struct *task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
  pid_t parent_pid = 0;

  if (task != NULL) {
    if (task->real_parent != NULL) {
        parent_pid = task->real_parent->tgid;
    }
  }


  // Insert into the hash map only if the PID doesn't exist yet
  if (bpf_map_update_elem(&execs, &pid, &empty_event, BPF_NOEXIST) != 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  struct event *event = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&execs, &pid);
  if (!event) {
    return 0;
  }

  // Update event data
  event->pid = pid;
  event->ppid = parent_pid;
  event->args_count = 0;
  event->args_size = 0;
  event->start_timestamp = ts;
  bpf_get_current_comm(&event->comm, sizeof(event->comm));

  unsigned int ret = 0;

  // Get additional arguments
  event->args_count++;
#pragma unroll
  for (int i = 1; i < TOTAL_MAX_ARGS; i++) {
    char *argp;
    bpf_probe_read_user(&argp, sizeof(argp), &((char **)(ctx->args[1]))[i]);
    if (!argp) {
      break; // Stop if there are no more arguments
    }

    if (event->args_size > LAST_ARG) {
      break; // Stop if we exceed the max argument size
    }

    ret =
        bpf_probe_read_user_str(&event->args[event->args_size], ARGSIZE, argp);
    if (ret > ARGSIZE) {
      break; // Stop if argument string is too large
    }

    event->args_count++;
    event->args_size += ret;
  }

  // Check if there are more arguments beyond the max
  char *extra_argp;
  bpf_probe_read_user(&extra_argp, sizeof(extra_argp),
                      &((char **)(ctx->args[1]))[TOTAL_MAX_ARGS]);
  if (extra_argp) {
    event->args_count++; // Count extra arguments if they exist
  }

  return 0;
}

// Tracepoint for sys_exit_execve
SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_exit_execve")
int tracepoint__syscalls__sys_exit_execve(
    struct trace_event_raw_sys_exit *ctx) {
  u64 id = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
  pid_t pid = (pid_t)id;
  u64 ts = bpf_ktime_get_ns();

  struct event *event = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&execs, &pid);
  if (!event) {
    return 0;
  }

  // Update event data (return value and end timestamp)
  event->retval = ctx->ret;
  event->end_timestamp = ts;

  // Get the process name (comm)
  bpf_get_current_comm(&event->comm, sizeof(event->comm));

  // Submit the event to the perf event map
  size_t len = EVENT_SIZE(event);
  if (len <= sizeof(*event)) {
    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &events, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU, event, len);
  }

  // Cleanup the event from the hash map
  bpf_map_delete_elem(&execs, &pid);
  return 0;
}

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";

This is my code using libbpf framework to trace sys_enter_execve&sys_exit_execve to get which process is run and exit. I want to get parent pid to check who run this process, but i can't. the code where has problem is
if (task != NULL) {
    if (task->real_parent != NULL) {
        parent_pid = task->real_parent->tgid;
    }
  }

the error msg is
libbpf: prog 'tracepoint__syscalls__sys_enter_execve': BPF program load failed: Permission denied
libbpf: prog 'tracepoint__syscalls__sys_enter_execve': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --
0: R1=ctx() R10=fp0
; int tracepoint__syscalls__sys_enter_execve( @ execsnoop.bpf.c:26
0: (bf) r6 = r1                       ; R1=ctx() R6_w=ctx()
; u64 id = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid(); @ execsnoop.bpf.c:31
1: (85) call bpf_get_current_pid_tgid#14      ; R0_w=scalar()
; pid_t pid = (pid_t)id; @ execsnoop.bpf.c:32
2: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -4) = r0         ; R0_w=scalar() R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
; u64 ts = bpf_ktime_get_ns(); @ execsnoop.bpf.c:33
3: (85) call bpf_ktime_get_ns#5       ; R0_w=scalar()
4: (bf) r8 = r0                       ; R0_w=scalar(id=1) R8_w=scalar(id=1)
5: (b7) r9 = 0                        ; R9_w=0
; struct task_struct *task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task(); @ execsnoop.bpf.c:36
6: (85) call bpf_get_current_task#35          ; R0=scalar()
; if (task != NULL) { @ execsnoop.bpf.c:39
7: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+4        ; R0=scalar(umin=1)
; if (task->real_parent != NULL) { @ execsnoop.bpf.c:40
8: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r0 +1584)
R0 invalid mem access 'scalar'
processed 9 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 1 peak_states 1 mark_read 1
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
libbpf: prog 'tracepoint__syscalls__sys_enter_execve': failed to load: -13
libbpf: failed to load object 'execsnoop_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'execsnoop_bpf': -13
Failed to load and verify BPF skeleton

beside, i get the vmlinux.h by bpftool btf dump file /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux format c > vmlinux.h, it should not have problem (I think...)

bpf_get_current_task returns a pointer to struct task_struct, but in eBPF you are not allowed to directly de-reference kernel memory, you have to use a helper to do that.
Breaking down the log
; struct task_struct *task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task(); @ execsnoop.bpf.c:36
6: (85) call bpf_get_current_task#35          ; R0=scalar()

bpf_get_current_task is called, the return value is R0, which is a scalar so "just a meaningless number" according to the verifier.
; if (task != NULL) { @ execsnoop.bpf.c:39
7: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+4        ; R0=scalar(umin=1)

Null checking the return value is allowed, no memory lookup happens.
; if (task->real_parent != NULL) { @ execsnoop.bpf.c:40
8: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r0 +1584)
R0 invalid mem access 'scalar'

But when doing task->real_parent you do a memory lookup at r0 +1584, and that isn't allowed.
For reference this bit of the code:
  // Get the parent PID of the current process
  struct task_struct *task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
  pid_t parent_pid = 0;

  if (task != NULL) {
    if (task->real_parent != NULL) {
        parent_pid = task->real_parent->tgid;
    }
  }

To fix it you need to call bpf_probe_read_kernel to get the parent pointer. Same goes for when accessing ->tgid otherwise that will cause the next verifier error.
// Get the parent PID of the current process
struct task_struct *task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
pid_t parent_pid = 0;

if (task != NULL) {
  struct task_struct *parent_task;
  bpf_probe_read_kernel(&parent_task, sizeof(parent_task), &task->real_parent);
  if (parent_task != NULL) {
    bpf_probe_read_kernel(&parent_pid, sizeof(parent_pid), &parent_task->tgid)
  }
}

Final bit of advice, it would be better to use bpf_core_read here since you are accessing internal kernel data structures. It will ensure your program works on other machines as well. You will need to include libbpf's bpf_core_read.h to get access to CO-RE functions.

Thinks!, it works, actually I found a Macro BPF_CORE_READ is more convenient.

However, I still have some questions. When I use BCC to do the same work, I can directly read fields from task_struct, which is a bit confusing.   struct task_struct *task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();   data.parent_pid = task->real_parent->tgid;

I cannot explain that. Looking at other BCC examples, they also use BPF_CORE_READ https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/b384150b3afd0715e5e7cfd4b15e564b38b2d587/libbpf-tools/exitsnoop.bpf.c#L45. It could also be that bpf_get_current_task_bpf() is used instead like here https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/b384150b3afd0715e5e7cfd4b15e564b38b2d587/tools/opensnoop.py#L357-L358. But that does not seem to be the case in your code quote
